# cURL downloading corrupt files from Veeva

Tags: php, cakephp, curl

I have a function which downloads a file from Veeva Vault. The files are the proper size, so I know at least I'm grabbing what I'm supposed to, but they are damaged and cannot be opened. I can manually go and download them from Veeva and they open fine, so I know the files themselves aren't the issue.

```
public function GetDocumentByUrl($url, $filename)
{
    $this->Auth(); //sets $this->sessID

    $urldata = explode("/", $url);

    $count = 0;
    foreach($urldata as $key => $value)
    {
      if( $value == "documents")
      {
          $count++;
          $id = $urldata[$count];
          break;
      }
      else
      {
          $count++;
      }
    }

    $type = $this->GetDocumentInfo($id, self::VVFILEEXT);

    $fullFilename = $filename . "." . $type;

    set_time_limit(0);
    $fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/' . $fullFilename, 'w+');

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json;charset=UTF-8", "Authorization: ".$this->sessID));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    $json_response = curl_exec($ch);
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    if($status != 200)
    {
    die('Error:  call to URL $url failed with status "' . $status .'", response "' . $json_response. '", curl_error "' . curl_error($curl) . '", curl_errno "'  . curl_errno($curl). '"');
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
}
```

I've tried adding CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER and CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER but that only returned a corrupt file 1kb in size.

I've also tried setting the content-type in CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER to "application/pdf" and “application/octet-stream” but neither helped.

Here's the Veeva API documentation: http://developer.veevavault.com/?page_id=951#Retrieve_Document_File

Comment: corrupted how? did you try opening one of the bad files in a text editor? If you haven't EXACTLY replicated what your browser is doing, you could be downloading an html error page or something, which you'd be blindly writing out to the proper filename.

Comment: I don't know how its corrupted. When trying to open a .doc file I get a message saying "Word was unable to read this document. It may be corrupted." Opening a pdf in Adobe Reader gives the message "There was an error opening this document. The file is damaged and could not be repaired." I doubt its an error page because the file sizes are what they should be, but I could be wrong. Opening it in a text editor basically gives thousands of lines of gibberish.